# How to get a cell in a range by the value of the cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets table and have this google apps script:

```
//function formatReport(){
 // let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 // let header = sheet.getRange('A1:C1');
 // header.setBackground('#eeeeee')
//}

function getCellByValue(cValue){
  

}

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

console.log(sheet.getRange('D2:D1001').getCellByValue('@bongo').toString());


const doGet = (event = {}) => {
  const { parameter } = event;
  const { type = 'badrequest' } = parameter;

    if (type == 'get'){
      
      let select = '3';


      var name = sheet.getRange('A' + select).getValue();
      var icon = sheet.getRange('B' + select).getValue();
      var message = sheet.getRange('C' + select).getValue();
    }
   


    let jsonTempl = {
        'type': type,
        'name': name,
        'icon': icon,
        'message': message
    };
    let myJSON = JSON.stringify(jsonTempl);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(myJSON).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
};



function doPost(e) {
    return true;
}
```

I need to get a cell from a range by only using the value of the cell. For example if I had a range A1:A3, with the values being 'first, second, third', I would want to get second in the range by only using the name 'second';

The Example you posted in your comment:

```
function findInRange(range, findtext) {
  let ranger = sheet.getRange(range);
  for (var tick = 0; tick > ranger.getValues().length; tick++) {
    if (ranger.getValues()[tick] == findtext) {
      var out = tick;
    }
    console.log(ranger.getvalues()[tick]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting I found the answer

```
  function findInRange(range,findtext){
    let ranger = sheet.getRange(range);

    var tickr = 0;
    while(tickr < ranger.getValues().length){
    

      if (ranger.getValues()[tickr] == findtext){
        var out = tickr;
      }
      tickr += 1;
    }
    return out;
  }
```

In the range parameter, you just input the range, then the text is a string for the text looked for. It returns the number in that range if it was found. If it was not found then it outputs undefined.